Changing apache2 web directory to a different drive
Ubuntu 24.04.1
I have 3 websites and 1 of those with Nextcloud under it. I can see all secure online.
<shock.pics> <shockfamily.site> <https://shocktography.pics> this one has <shocktography.pics/nextcloud>.
I want to move /var/www/html to a different drive /media/ken/www/www/html.
my fstab is:
LABEL=www /media/ken/www auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,x-udisks-auth,x-gvfs-name=www 0 0

my sites available.conf that works is:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin ken@kmshock.com
        ServerName shock.pics
        ServerAlias www.shock.pics
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/shock.pics
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shock.pics_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shock.pic_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.shock.pics [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =shock.pics
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ken@kmshock.com
    ServerName shockfamily.site
    ServerAlias www.shockfamily.site
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/shockfamily.site
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shockfamily.site_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shockfamily.site_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =shockfamily.site [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.shockfamily.site
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ken@kmshock.com
    ServerName shocktography.pics
    ServerAlias www.shocktography.pics
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/shocktography.pics   
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shocktography.pics_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shocktography.pics_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.shocktography.pics [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =shocktography.pics
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
            DocumentRoot /var/www/html/shocktography.pics/nextcloud
        ServerName shocktography.pics
    <Directory /var/www/html/shocktography.pics/nextcloud>
        Options +FollowSymlinks
        AllowOverride All

        <IfModule mod_dav.c>
            Dav off
        </IfModule>

        SetEnv Home /var/www/html/shocktography.pics/nextcloud
        SetEnv HTTP_HOME /var/www/html/shocktography.pics/nextcloud
    </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nextcloud_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nextcloud_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

I have changed it to:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin ken@kmshock.com
        ServerName shock.pics
        ServerAlias www.shock.pics
        DocumentRoot /media/ken/www/www/html/shock.pics
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shock.pics_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shock.pic_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.shock.pics [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =shock.pics
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ken@kmshock.com
    ServerName shockfamily.site
    ServerAlias www.shockfamily.site
    DocumentRoot /media/ken/www/www/html/shockfamily.site
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shockfamily.site_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shockfamily.site_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =shockfamily.site [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.shockfamily.site
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin ken@kmshock.com
    ServerName shocktography.pics
    ServerAlias www.shocktography.pics
    DocumentRoot /media/ken/www/www/html/shocktography.pics 
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shocktography.pics_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/shocktography.pics_access.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.shocktography.pics [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =shocktography.pics
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
            DocumentRoot /media/ken/www/www/html/shocktography.pics/nextcloud
        ServerName shocktography.pics


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nextcloud_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/nextcloud_access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<Directory /media/ken/www/www/html>
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
            Dav off
    </IfModule>

    SetEnv Home /media/ken/www/www/html
    SetEnv HTTP_HOME /media/ken/www/www/html
</Directory>

My good apache2.conf is:
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

I change it to:
<Directory /media/ken/www/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

I have change permission and owner:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo find /media/ken/www/www/html -type d -exec chmod 2750 {} \+
sudo find /media/ken/www/www/html -type f -exec chmod 640 {} \+

I still get 403 permission denied.

This is most likely the result of apparmor preventing Apache from reading /media/ken. You will either need to disable apparmor or add the new directories to the Apache permission configuration.
